# How to implement payout method on specific card by node.js and stripe?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

- Hello everyone. My problem is next: i have a stripe account. in mobile app clients are buying tickets and sending their moneys on this stripe billing. and now, after some event, an organizer of event must to payout the moneys from clients. how can i to do that? i mean, that which part of huge stripe api is tge best for these case.

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to set up your bank account or debt card for [payouts](https://stripe.com/docs/payouts). You can even set up automatic payouts.